# Are topical acne medications even allowed under the eyelid?

Tags: topical-cream-gel, acne, face, eyelids

Topical acne medications are supposed to be used all over the face. However,  the skin under the eyelids is much thinner and weaker, which makes it completely different. I assume any medication should barely be used there.